# Designing Tables Sql Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Good Morning, 
in the design of a database, I have a table (TabA's call it) that could have relationships with four other tables. In the sense that this table can be connected both with the first of four, and with the second, and the third to the fourth, but could not have links with them; or it could have one (with any of the tables), or two links (always with two of any of them), and so on.

The table TabA I added four fields that refer to the four tables which could be "null" when they do not have any connection.

Wondering is this the kind of optimal design (say the four fields in the TabA) or you can make a better design for this type of situation?

Many thanks for your reply.

dave

Comment: Can you please provide us with more information, and examples about your tables, and fields inside them.

Comment: If I understand correctly, then what you have proposed sounds correct. If you have a table with 4 relationships to four separate tables, then you should have 4 columns, each of them a foreign key to the relevant table. If necessary you can manage the minimum/maximum number of relationships with check constraints (e.g if `Column1` is null, then `Column2` must not be null).

Comment: Then, the example is: http://i.imgur.com/gW8uRhD.jpg, where I have relations, but they might not even be there; my question: the design is the best or maybe there would be another where maybe I might not have the four fields in the table and maybe somehow codify and simplify the database. thank you again

Comment: You seem to be saying that if you have a related record in one table you must also have one in another.  If that's the case, there is probably room for improvement.

Comment: Since you are still in the design phase I would recommend dropping the ridiculous TBL_ prefix to every table. Also once you start doing things like creating tables for numbered levels you need to stop and back up. That is not a good design. What happens when you need a 4th level? You have to add tables, relationships and change code. It is hard to offer much more help because all the tables only have 1 column in what you posted.

Answer (score 1):

In answer to the question and clarification in your comment, the answer is that your design can't be improved in terms of the number of foreign key columns.  Having a specific foreign key column for every potential foreign key relationship is a best practice design.

However, the schema design itself seems questionable.  I don't have enough information to tell whether the "Distributori_[N]_Livello" tables are a truly hierarchical structure or not.  If it is, it is often possible to use a self-referential table for hierarchical structures rather than a set of N tables, as the diagram you linked seems to use.  If you are able to refactor your design in such a way, it might be possible to reduce the number of foreign key columns required.

Whether this is possible or not is not for me to say given the data provided.

Comment: My mistake: http://i.imgur.com/tYZRgfk.jpg. I was wrong to post the image: the name "Distributori_1_Livello" etc., does not represent a hierarchical structure but are only volumes of names. Let's say we have the TBL_AMMINISTRAZIONE, TBL_DISTRIBUTORI, TBL_RIVENDITORI, TBL_VENDITORI E TBL_CLIENTI.

Comment: In that case, if that design is what you need, the foreign keys you have should be correct.